# How to choose bootstrap confidence interval type from boot.ci in R?

Tags: r, bootstrap

The [boot.ci documentation](https://rweb.stat.umn.edu/R/library/boot/html/boot.ci.html) in R says there are five different types of confidence interval that `boot.ci` will return:

- norm (normal approximation)
- basic
- stud (studentized)
- perc (percentile)
- bca (bias-corrected, accelerated)

BCa looked pretty good, but it seems really slow for my data.

How should I choose which one to use?

Comment: From what I've read, BCa and percentile are considered the technically superior. I have found percentile to be reasonably well behaved in difficult situations (e.g. small sample size or discontinuous data). The following article is helpful: http://www.tau.ac.il/~saharon/Boot/10.1.1.133.8405.pdf

Comment: There are actually more than 5.  There is BC which does not include the use of an acceleration constant, two percentile methods (Efron's and Hall's)  and iterated bootstrap.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I meant that boot.ci will return. Clarified in the question.

Comment: So the procedure will give you only those 5 choices.  But percentile method is ambiguous.  Is it Efron's or Hall's percentile method?

Comment: The documentation for boot.ci says, "The formulae on which the calculations are based can be found in Chapter 5 of Davison and Hinkley (1997)."  Dunno if that's helpful.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thanks. Not really helpful. Statisticians always mention books, but the rest of the world puts their info online explicitly, where we can refer to it.

Comment: @MichaelChernick No idea.

Comment: @SalMangiafico How small the sample should roughly be then so that we opt for the `percentile` option and not `bca`?

Comment: @Jabro , I have no idea what sample size would be too small for BCa to be stable.  Honestly, it would worthwhile to simulate some data that are similar to what you have, in terms of sample size and distribution, and calculate the confidence interval with the different methods on many simulated samples. ... Or if you want to do something really fun, do this with different sample sizes and see at what sample size the BCa method returns stable results.

Answer (score 2):

If your replicates are not normally distributed, do not choose $normal$.

$Basic$ can give you intervals that are out of the range of your replicated data; e.g. your bootstrapped replicates range between 2-200 but your lower confidence interval is -5.

For $student's$ CI, you need to pass a variance alongside whatever statistics (e.g. mean, median) you are dealing with. I would prefer this over $bca$ if you cannot generate a large number of replicates that can satisfy $bca$. If the number of replicates are small, the $bca$ intervals become unstable. One way of checking the stability is to generate many sets of replicates and identify corresponding confidence limits - most likely you will notice that the range of confidence limits based on $bca$ is wider than the rest.

I don't even know why they have the $percentile$ method, the most confusing of all five.

Comment: A cliched question: "If the number of replicates are small" -- how small is "small"?

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Ironically, while you find percentile the most confusing, I see it recommended in a lot of places, because it's conceptually simple (just take 2.5 and 97.5 percentile). I don't know whether it's good. I thought I read in a paper by Efron et al. that it can be biased, hence the BCa.

Answer (score 0):

I found https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5279 to be one of the clearest and easiest-to-read reference.

In contrast to other sources the author recommends to avoid the basic confidence interval and rather use the easy percentile or some t-test based one. I'm not sure whether it touches upon BCA.